# How do I get an array of days of the month with Perl Date::Manip?

Tags: perl

I'm using [Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip) for a variety of things, and want to create an array of days of the month.
I *think* I need:

```
@date = &ParseRecur("2010:4:0:0:0:0:0");
```

but, it doesn't do it.
I've read & reread the man page but can't get the syntax.

```
@date = &ParseRecur("2010:4:0:1:0:0:0"); 
@date = &ParseRecur("2010:4:0:1*:0:0:0");
```

don't work either!

Answer (score 2):

You could build the list with your own loop, instead of using ParseRecur.

```
$month = 4;
for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
    my $date = UnixDate( "$month/$day/2010", "%m-%d-%Y" );
    push( @list, $date ) if (defined $date);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the man pages:
**"There are a small handful of English strings which can be parsed in place of a numerical recur description."**
Check out the examples in the man page.

So, if you want an array of days of a month - say for June in 2010 you would do:

```
@dates = ParseRecur("every day in June 2010");
```